# fetch firebase realtime database to web page with pagination

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data from the firebase database, MySql was so easy to retrieve data, but I am so confused with firebase. below is my data from the firebase database.[image]

under the Product, the first child is my category id and its child is a subcategory. I would like to retrieve data from the firebase and display on the html web page with pagination. I tried the below code.

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    databaseURL: "https://XXXXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

var userDataRef = firebase.database().ref("Products/").orderByKey();
userDataRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  var key = childSnapshot.key;
  var childData = childSnapshot.val();              

  var proname = childSnapshot.val().proname;
  var promrp = childSnapshot.val().promrp;

  $("#name").append(proname);
  $("#mrp").append(promrp);

  });
});
```

I hope you understand my concern.

Comment: So, seems ok the above except some adjustment for UI. Isn't it? what is your exact question

Comment: I want to display the data of product name, mrp and rest of the fields on the HTML page

Comment: So, when you retrieve the data into an array, you like to list the array something like this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fdlwq9

Comment: yes you are correct but i want to display all the records and if possible i want to add pagination or load more option

Comment: ,Apart from Firebase, you may use the Pagination library of Jquery: https://pagination.js.org/

Comment: thank you for the great info, but how to display my data in HTML first child is a category and its child is a subcategory.

Comment: if you don't mine, in order to make some test, could you download `Products` data from Firebase console and share json data with mail or somehow.

Comment: please share your email

Comment: You can send to netcat16@gmail.com

Comment: please check i sent a mail

Comment: please check this link again. Is something you want? https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fdlwq9?file=index.js  (Or please provide your expected view in order to do so)

Comment: i already got this result to thank for your help. but my question is how to print the first array child and inside fields. now its printing 1, bags,etc but i want to print 1,1,proname,ect.,